# adding and removing divs dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi guys I've got stuck with this. The add works fine the removing is not working. I can alert the figures but the selection is not work. I have just added the remove function.
 this i have modified it and it works thanks

```
    <script>
            $(function () {
                // Handler for .ready() called.
                lastPassengerID = $('.passengersInsert').children().last().attr('class');
            });
            //addPassenger();
// A $( document ).ready() block.
            function addPassenger() {
                var passengers = $('.passengersInsert').children().length;
                if (passengers > 1) {
                    //var lastPassengerID = $('.passengersInsert').children().last().attr('class');
                    //var id = $('.passengersInsert').children().attr('id');
                    lastPassengerID = parseInt(lastPassengerID.replace('P', ''));
                } else {
                    lastPassengerID = 0;
                }

                if (passengers === 0) {
                    //alert('passengers' + passengers);
                    $(".checkbox1").remove();
                }

                var seqNo = passengers + 1;
                if (seqNo > 1) {
                    var defaultText = "PASSENGER NO " + seqNo + "";
                } else {
                    defaultText = "LEAD PASSENGER";
                }

                //alert('last ID' + lastPassengerID);

                var template = '<div class="P' + seqNo + '"><div id="' + seqNo + '" class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading">' + defaultText + '<div class="col-xs-2 row pull-right" id="addRemove"><input id="neg" class="col-xs-5 pull-left" type="button" value="-" onclick="removePassenger('+ seqNo +')"> <input id="pos" class="col-xs-5" type="button" value="+" onclick="addPassenger()"></div></div><br/><div class="row">';
                template += '<div id="C' + seqNo + '" class="col-xs-12" style="/*border:1px solid blue;*/"><div class="col-xs-12" style="/*border: 1px solid green;*/">';
                template += '<div class="row"><em><h5 class="col-xs-12" >Contact Details</h5></em></div><br/></div>';
                template += '<div class="col-xs-12"><div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-left" style="/*border: 1px solid red;*/"><div class="input-group col-xs-12"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="FName' + seqNo + '"></div></div>';
                template += '<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-right"><div class="input-group col-xs-12"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> </span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="SName' + seqNo + '"></div></div>&nbsp;</div><div class=" col-xs-12">';
                template += '<div class="row"><div id="C' + seqNo + '" class=" col-xs-12"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="row"><em><h5 class="col-xs-12">Address</h5></em></div><div class="checkbox' + seqNo + '"><label class="row col-xs-12 "><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox' + seqNo + ' col-xs-1" name="PAddress' + seqNo + '" id="PAddress' + seqNo + '" value=""> Same as Lead Passenger </label></div></div></div></div>';
                template += '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-left"><div class="input-group col-xs-12"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span><input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Door No." name="DoorNumber' + seqNo + '"></div></div>';
                template += '<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Street Name" name="Road' + seqNo + '"></div></div></div></div><br/>';
                template += '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Town /City" name="Town' + seqNo + '"></div></div>';
                template += '<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Post Code /Zip Code" name="PostCode' + seqNo + '"></div></div></div></div><br/>';
                template += '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="County/State" name="County' + seqNo + '"></div></div><div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">';
                template += '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Country" name="Country' + seqNo + '"></div></div></div></div><br/>';
                template += '<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact No" name="Tel' + seqNo + '"></div></div>';
                template += '<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="Email' + seqNo + '"></div></div></div></div><br/></div></div></div></div></div>';

                //$('.passengersInsert').append(template);
                $(template).appendTo('.passengersInsert');
                $(".checkbox1").remove();
                $('.P' + seqNo).css('border', '1px solid red');
            }
            //var id = $('div').attr('id');
            function removePassenger(seqNo) {
                $('.P' + seqNo).remove(); /*nothing happens*/
                $('.P' + seqNo).css('border', '1px solid blue');/*this highlights the '-' buttons margin. instead of the expected element.*/
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: seems fine, where is your add/remove function.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/dm96awr0/

Comment: code formatting

Comment: Hi guys, any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1)
The variable `lastPassengerID` is defined inside the `addPassenger` function and therefore bound to its scope. The variable is **not** available outside the `addPassenger` function and its therefore `undefined` inside the `removePassenger` function.

To use it as you intend inside the `removePassenger` function you need to declare the variable in a scope both functions are part of or simply declare it as a global variable right before you open the `addPassenger` function.

2)
The first line of your `removePassenger` function does contain a coding error:

```
$('P+lastPassengerID+').remove();
```

should be

```
$('.P'+lastPassengerID).remove();
```

so the the contents of `lastPassengerID` are actually combined with the string "P" which results in a valid selector. Additionally you need to add a dot (`.`) at the start of the selector to identify the selector as an class selector so it actually matches a class.

Comment: Thanks Fabian. this helped me to get to my solution. I have reposted the final script. How do i flag your answer as helpful?

Comment: Well you can upvote posts or you can flag this answer as the accepted answer by clicking the check-icon below the upvote/downvote buttons. You can even do both.

Regarding your edit: If you want to show newer code versions you should always add them as seperate parts marked as such (e.g. by "edit:") so everyone can still see the initial problem.